# How to implement a custom SearchView layout?

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to implement a custom SearchView layout. I have successfully changed many of the attributes of android.support.v7.appcompat.SearchView such as background color and text color, but I am wanting to customize even more. So I made my own search_view_layout.xml file, but I cannot figure out how to implement it. This is the search_view_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_gravity="top"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:padding="5dp">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/leftMenuSearch"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:queryHint="What are you looking for?"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:maxWidth="1000dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@color/beanBlue"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my menu_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
          app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
          app:actionLayout="@layout/search_view_layout"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_cart"
          android:title="Cart"
          android:icon="@drawable/cart_icon"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

and this is my toolbar.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="15dp"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapse_back_button">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bean"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/beanBlue"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is what the toolbar looks like before the search icon is pressed:

[image: Toolbar before Search]

and this is what I want the SearchView to look like when the search icon is pressed:

[image: Toolbar with SearchView]

How do I implement this custom SearchView layout in my android project?

Comment: From the looks of it you only want to change the cancel button right?
`closeIcon` attribute should help you replace the icon

Comment: Yes, but I want the closeIcon on the right side of the SearchView

Comment: Its best not to change such patterns. But if you do, you'll have to change the actionViewClass attribute value. Extend SearchView to return your own layout

Comment: So create a class to handle the custom SearchView and then point the actionViewClass attribute to that class?

Comment: Yep, you are exactly right. The actionLayout is not needed if you have an class that is providing it

Comment: Could you point me to an example of the class implementation or answer the question with one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105606/discussion-between-akash-ramani-and-cjones3724).

Answer (score 1):

```
final int layoutResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SearchView_layout, R.layout.abc_search_view);
inflater.inflate(layoutResId, this, true);
```

I found the code above in `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.java`, you can define your custom layout in xml, and just add the `app:layout="@layout/resId"`.

**Notice**

You have to read the source code to provide all views with the same ids, or it will crash with `NullPointerException`. For detail, you can look at the source of `SearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)`